# Как сделать так, чтобы появлялся не title страницы, а заголовок новости?

Tags: html, вёрстка, соцсети

Новости реализованы таким образом: http://rkit.ru/news/ Внизу каждой новости есть иконка для того, чтобы поделиться новостями. Если ее нажать появляется окошко, в котором новогодняя фотография и тайтл страницы. Как сделать так, чтобы была дата и название новости, а если у новости нет фото, то и картинка не выводилась? Может, есть другие виджеты фейсбука? Кто-то сталкивался с этим? Сайт стоит на Битриксе.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой протокол как Open Graph: http://ogp.me/

По сути, это некоторые мета теги, которые подсказывают социальным сетям и другим "роботам" что брать со страницы.

```
<title>Заголовок вкладки в браузере</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Заголовок для ссылки в ВК" />
```

Как-то так.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.title = "…";
```

или

```
$('title').text('...')
```

Comment: Тайтл там и так сейчас меняется, не помогло.

Comment: социальные сети тянут контент простым роботом и на javascript не обращают внимания. Поэтому подобные способы не работают.